# Pandas read sql query giving an error called sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: mapping or sequence expected for parameters?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I can't seem to get this to work, I used this format in the past on older versions but it doesn't seem to be working anymore.

```
id = 1

engine = sql.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://{}:{}@{}/{}?driver={}'.format(USERNAME, PASSWORD,SERVER_NAME, DATABASE_NAME,driver))

df = pd.read_sql('SELECT [x_id] FROM tableName WHERE [x_id] = ?', engine, params=(id))
```

I keep getting errors like sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: mapping or sequence expected for parameters. Is ? not a parameter anymore?

Comment: i think it's (id,)

Comment: @siggemannen - thanks, this saved the day - worked with trino and sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be with the way you are passing the params argument to the pd.read_sql function. In your code, you are passing a single value of id as the params argument, but params should be a list or tuple of parameter values. You can try changing the line:

```
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT [x_id] FROM tableName WHERE [x_id] = ?', engine, params=[id])
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, but siggemannen comment did